# Show Advertisement (AdSense) only for specific labels in blogspot

Tags: html, blogger, adsense

I want to show advertisement just in specific labels like here:

But that doesn't work. It shows me nothing. How can I fix that problem? I want to show Google AdSense for the Labels Gartenblog, Foodblog, Reiseblog, Fotoblog and Blogging, if there aren't these labels it should show another advertisement. How can I do this?

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels none (label => label.name in ["Gartenblog","Foodblog","Familienblog","Reiseblog","Fotoblog","Blogging"])'>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == ["Gartenblog","Foodblog","Familienblog","Reiseblog","Fotoblog","Blogging"])'>
```

It works fine if I just use one label, but not for multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for length:

```
<b:if cond='(data:post.labels where (label => label.name in ["Gartenblog","Foodblog","Familienblog","Reiseblog","Fotoblog","Blogging"])).length gt 0'>
  <!-- Ad One -->
<b:else/>
  <!-- Ad Two-->
</b:if>
```